# Magento 1.9 Autherize.net CIM charges twice

Tags: payment, magento-1.9, authorize.net, cim

We have an issue with customers getting double charged.

Today we noticed that another batch of orders was charged twice in Authorize. We don't see any sign of a second charge in the notes on Magento but the customer did receive a shipment notification from Magento on the day she was charged again. This particular order came into the system on 11/14 and was processed and shipped on 11/18. This customer emailed us today that she was charged again on 12/14/22. No one on our team has opened that order since 11/18.

Does anyone have an idea on this issue? On 11/14 we changed the settings in Authorize that allowed us to have less strict rules for having a matching billing zip and street address so we could allow the order to go through and then check ourselves if we would allow the order to be processed. None of these orders were marked as fraud though.

Comment: No experience with authorize.net, but this doesn't seem like an issue with M1.9.

Answer (score 0):

Given the detail you provided that the identical charge occurred again on the same day of the following month, it seems most likely you may have accidentally turned on a recurring payment option, either as an option on a virtual product of some kind or in one of your specific payment payment processing settings in the Magento Admin Panel.

Depending upon which extensions you may have installed, two other strong possibilities to check would be:

1. A 3rd party payment processor has given your customer the option to select a recurring charge and they accidentally activated that option.
2. An extension allowing customers to manage/schedule reorders through the Customer Account Management section of the Magento storefront has been accidentally activated by the customer.

Either of these two options becomes far more likely if this is occurring on *some* but not *all* orders.